# real analysis convergence of limit

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits

Hi i have aquestion here which is whether

> $x_n = \frac{1}{n}$ for $n$ odd 
>   and $x_n = 1$ for $n$ even

does the sequence converge?

i am thinking of using the ratio test here. 
will it work that way?

Comment: it doesn't converge. try to exhibit two subsequences convergent to different limits

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Say it converges: $x_n \to L$. Then by a well known theorem we must have that every subsequence of $(x_n)$ must converge to the same limit. However, if you take the subsequence $(x_{2n}) = 1 \to 1$ and $(x_{2n+1} ) = \frac{1}{n} \to 0 $. We have found that $(x_n)$ contains two subsequences with different limits. This is an absurd. Hence, your sequence does not converge.

Answer (score 1):

There is a subsequence which converges to $0$ and another which converges to $1$, so the sequence does not converge.